# How to handle download preferences and plug in preferences in watir? I want to know the list of options available for them to use

Tags: ruby, watir

I have read that I can use the pattern below for passing options to Chrome driver in `Watir`,

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, opts
```

I am using the following code at the moment:

```
Options = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome options

browser = Watir::Browser.new(driver)
```

Please let me know what pattern I should use to pass options to Chrome driver. What are the different options available for plugins and download preferences?

Comment: @Justin Ko : Please clarify my understanding

Comment: You can look at http://watir.com/guides/chrome/ where the preferences example includes downloads. I don't know anything about plugins.